# How do U,V coordinates work?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I'm writing an application that calls for the conversion of image processing functions that take global x,y coordinates to ones that take u,v coordinates. How does the U,V coordinate system work?

Comment: It depends on how you define U,V in relationship to X,Y. It usually depends on what geometrical shape(s) or skewing are involved.

Answer (score 5):

UV maps are flattened representations of 3d geometry, with coordinate points usually corresponding to the verticies of a 3d dimensional object.

[image: UV]

Comment: So how would you convert between the two?

Comment: It depends on the geometry, but if you're just dealing with a 2d map, typically the bottom left corner is represented as UV [0,0], the top right as [1,1], upper left as [0,1] and bottom right as [1,0].

Answer (score 3):

From the outside, looking in:

### x,y,z coordinates are unbounded and absolute.

It's how we think of reality.  I'm 10' tall.  It's 3km to the store.

- It is unbounded - you can just keep going in any direction.
- It is absolute - a 1 meter in the x direction is the same everywhere.
- It has units.  1 in the x direction is meaningless.  1 cm or 1 km?

### u,v,w coordinates are bounded and relative.

For a 2d surface being texture mapped, this is UV in the x and y directions.

- It is bounded from 0.0 -> 1.0.  You are 1.0 tall.  There is no you to texture at 1.1
- It is relative.  Regardless of height, you look for someone's face around 0.9.
- It is unit-less.  The "unit" is the thing it's relative to.  In this example, 0.9 "you".

These features, and modern floating point performance, make it a very useful coordinate for mapping textures on shapes.

Answer (score 1):

U, V, and W are standard ways to express vectors in terms of direction/length, where X, Y, and Z represent a single point. If this is the intent of the library you're using, then it should translate directly from UVW to XYZ for the most part, just with a different spirit behind it.